# Determine Text Orientation in a PDF

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf.js

Is there a way that I can detect whether the text in a page is in Landscape or Portrait Orientation using JS or any libraries? I cannot rely on width > height, as there are pages that are rotated as well. [image: Rotated Page with Portrait Orientation] vs [image: Rotated Page with Landscape Orientation]

I cannot rely on comparing Width and Height, or checking if the page is rotated, because both these pages are rotated 90 degrees, but I cannot figure out how to detect the text's orientation.

I also do some preprocessing on the PDF using Node.js and pdfjs. So if that has any API/library to help me get the required information I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using tesseract which is mainly used for OCR conversion. I am using it with PHP but you can also use it with JS:
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/580/how-to-convert-images-to-text-with-pure-javascript-using-tesseract-js

Tesseract can detect orientation. Here is some information on it using Python:
[Is it possible to check orientation of an image before passing it through pytesseract ocr module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55119504/is-it-possible-to-check-orientation-of-an-image-before-passing-it-through-pytess)

All you would need to do is to adapt this to Javascript using the tool of the first link above.